# Oracle 11g - populate table rows with constant value from sequence

Tags: oracle11g, constants, sequence

I am converting some legacy SQL Loader scripts to external tables. External tables are up and running, so the next step is to populate tables with data from external tables. SQL Loader script looks something like this:

```
Load Data                                                                   
Append 
Into Table my_table
Fields Terminated by "|"  Trailing Nullcols          
(                                                                               
    MY_COL                  "Trim(:SOME_COL)",                                          
    SESS_ID                 CONSTANT #$SESSION$#,
    FILEREC                 RECNUM,
    REC_ID                  SEQUENCE(MAX)
)
```

There is additional logic, when loading data with SQL Loader, such as session ID, which is next value from sequence, which is used as a constant for all rows in a batch. I was planning to do in a following way, but I can't use sequence in subquery (I also tried to use insert statement, but in that case, every record gets next value from sequence):

```
CREATE table my_table(
    my_col,
    session
)
AS SELECT
    e.my_col,
    my_seq.nextval
FROM my_external_table e;
```

Question - is there a way to populate all rows with constant value from `sequence.nextval`? I know I can do it in multiple steps, like create table, and then update session ID column, but I am wondering is there a way to do it in a single SQL statement (trying to avoid PL/SQL)? Planned result is following:

```
my_col  seq.nextval
aaaaaa  99
bbbbbb  99
cccccc  99
```

But I am getting following (when using insert statement):

```
my_col  seq.nextval
aaaaaa  99
bbbbbb  100
cccccc  101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seq.nextval` always returns the next value. You are looking for `seq.currval`.

Sadly, `seq.currval` requires that you previously use `seq.nextval` in that same session; and `currval` will then return the value you got by `nextval`. So, in a sql*loader operation, you are out of luck, since you cannot convince it to do a `seq.nextval` beforehand.

So, multiple steps is what you need.

Comment: Solution I came up with - insert current session ID in a table with `my_seq.nextval` and then select max session ID from that table into target table